# How to ensure only one instance of an AWS ECS scheduled task run at the same time?

Tags: amazon-web-services, cron, scheduled-tasks, amazon-ecs

Just like `cron`, AWS ECS Scheduled Tasks do not provide any built-in solution to prevent multiple instances of a scheduled task run at the same time.

One common way to solve this problem for `cron` is to create lock files.

An example that I found is https://github.com/bgentry/lock-smith. However, it says it is still in beta quality and has not been updated for several years.

Are there any other established solutions/utilities to solve this problem for ECS?

Answer (score 0):

What do you use to manage ECS? Terraform, some other IaC, or manually?
So far I got it just fine with Terraform having ECS (EC2), ASG for it (`1,1,1` for `min,max,desired`) and setting which allowed to kill current task before deploying new one, to have RAM to do so: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/ecs_service#deployment_minimum_healthy_percent

Some other answer I've read ([AWS ECS. How to ensure only one instance of a task is running?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62164808/aws-ecs-how-to-ensure-only-one-instance-of-a-task-is-running)) suggests that you may be not using ECS "service" functionality to its potential, and per https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/application/userguide/application-auto-scaling-scheduled-scaling.html you are encouraged to do so.

Comment: I think you are confusing ECS "services" (always running) with ECS "scheduled tasks" (periodic tasks, not running all the time).  Hence 'desired = 1' is not applicable