# AWS ECS. How to ensure only one instance of a task is running?

Tags: amazon-ecs

I'm wanting to setup an ECS task to schedule various other application tasks.

The "tasks" this task will schedule will mostly involve calling restful endpoints in another load balanced service.

I know there are other ways to do this, using cloudwatch to trigger a lambda etc. However this seems overly complex for what I need.

I was planning to just make a very simple, light-weight apline based image with a crontab to do the triggering of the restful calls.

This all seems easy enough. The only concern I have is that I would want to prevent, as far as possible, having multiple instances of this task running, even if only for a short period of time.

If my CI/CD pipeline triggers an update to this cron task, then there may be a short period of time, where the old and new task will be running simultaneously.

There may therefore be a small chance that a cron task could be triggered twice.

What I would like to do, is to have ECS stop the currently running task completely, before attempting to start the new one.

This seems to be contrary to the normal way it wants to work, where it will ensure the new task is up, and healthy before stopping the old one.

Is this possible, and if so, how do I configure it?

It's not a problem if my crons don't run for a period of time, but it could be a problem if any get triggered more than once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using ECS Service (which makes sure a particular number of tasks is always running and deploys via rolling or B/G deploy strategy which is not you desire) - how about using StopTask and RunTask api to control when a task is stopped and started - gives you complete control.

Comment: Yes, this would do the job. I could also integate this into CodePipeline to have it automatically stop the task when deploying new versions and start again afterwards. I'm actually leaning more now towards a more robust SQS solution, now that I have cloudwatch rules and lambda working, but this could be a fallback option.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using scheduled tasks, you could create an ECS service and use [scheduled scaling](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/application/userguide/application-auto-scaling-scheduled-scaling.html) to scale the desired service count to 1 and back down to zero.

Comment: I can see how this could be helpful in certain situations. However for my particular case, I have a number different application "tasks" to run at various intervals. I think what you're suggesting would require an ECS task per application "task", which might become a bit unwieldy to manage. I ended up going with cloudwatch rules and lambda to manage the schedules. It was a bit more effort to setup initially, but seemed like overall the most flexible and "correct" approach.

Comment: I've up-voted, as this suggestion actually has given me an idea for how to optimise ECS resources for other parts of my application.

Comment: How and when would it get set back down to zero when the task finishes?

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating an ECS service, there is a `maximumPercent` parameter, which if you set it to "100%" should prevent it from starting a new task while the old one is still running:

> If a service is using the rolling update (ECS) deployment type, the
> maximumPercent parameter represents an upper limit on the number of
> your service's tasks that are allowed in the RUNNING or PENDING state
> during a deployment, as a percentage of the desiredCount (rounded down
> to the nearest integer). This parameter enables you to define the
> deployment batch size. For example, if your service is using the
> REPLICA service scheduler and has a desiredCount of four tasks and a
> maximumPercent value of 200%, the scheduler may start four new tasks
> before stopping the four older tasks (provided that the cluster
> resources required to do this are available). The default
> maximumPercent value for a service using the REPLICA service scheduler
> is 200%.
>
> If a service is using either the blue/green (CODE_DEPLOY) or EXTERNAL
> deployment types and tasks that use the EC2 launch type, the maximum
> percent value is set to the default value and is used to define the
> upper limit on the number of the tasks in the service that remain in
> the RUNNING state while the container instances are in the DRAINING
> state. If the tasks in the service use the Fargate launch type, the
> maximum percent value is not used, although it is returned when
> describing your service.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/APIReference/API_DeploymentConfiguration.html