# Check if fargat task is already running before starting new one

Tags: amazon-web-services, scheduled-tasks, aws-fargate

I have a scheduled task running every hour which creates a new fargate task and it executes a script required for our service.

The issue what I face is that new fargate task has been created every hour as per the scheduled task definition, which leads to multiple tasks getting created and executing the same script in parallel.

I want to change it in a way that to create a new fargate task only when there are no similar tasks running.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/62178682/155892

Answer (score 1):

If you are using ECS Scheduled Tasks, which are triggered by AWS EventBridge schedules, there is no way to have EventBridge check if a task is already running before creating another task.

One option would be to have the EventBridge schedule trigger a Lambda function instead of the ECS Task. The Lambda function could query the ECS API to check if the task is already running, and then trigger a new ECS task only if one isn't running.

Another option would be to let EventBridge trigger a new ECS task every hour, but the startup script that runs in your ECS container check first if another task is running (either via the ECS API, or checking some sort of distributed lock you have built on DynamoDB or something) and quickly exiting if it detects another task is running.